# How I get random keys from keyboard for game controls?

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to make moving object using controls.
I'm trying to do this using Buttons. The code is

```
diskPosition = {50, 50}; left = False; right = False; up = False; down = False;

Manipulate[
 Graphics[Dynamic[
   If[left, diskPosition[[1]] += -.01]; 
   If[right, diskPosition[[1]] += .01];
   If[up, diskPosition[[2]] += .01]; 
   If[down, diskPosition[[2]] += -.01];
   {Yellow, Disk[diskPosition, 3]}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 140}}, Background -> Black
  ],
 Row[{Button["\[LongLeftArrow]", left = True; 
    right = up = down = False], 
   Column[{Button["\[UpArrow]", up = True; 
      right = left = down = False],
     Button["\[DownArrow]", down = True; right = up = left = False]}],
    Button["\[LongRightArrow]", right = True; 
    left = up = down = False]}]
 ]
```

I wonder if I can use random keys on the keyboard? 
I know how to get "Shift", "Ctrl" and "Alt" with CurrentValue[] but not how to get random keys from keyboard. Some suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "random keys."  If you mean how to process any user keydown, then `EventHandler` and `CurrentValue["EventKey"]` might be what you're looking for.  They can handle keydown events.
Note that all rules that match the event are processed.  Below for instance, if a "?" is pressed, `diskPosition` is set to a new random position *and* `label` is set to an empty string.

```
DynamicModule[{diskPosition = {50, 50}, diskRadius = 3, label = ""},
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[Dynamic[
    {Yellow, Disk[diskPosition, diskRadius], Darker@Red, 
     Text[label, diskPosition]}],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 140}}, Background -> Black],
  {"LeftArrowKeyDown"  :> (diskPosition[[1]] += -.1),
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (diskPosition[[1]] += .1),
   "UpArrowKeyDown"    :> (diskPosition[[2]] += .1),
   "DownArrowKeyDown"  :> (diskPosition[[2]] += -.1),
   {"KeyDown", "?"}    :> (diskPosition = {RandomReal[{3, 100 - 3}], RandomReal[{3, 140 - 3}]}),
   "KeyDown"           :> With[{char = CurrentValue["EventKey"]},
                            If[LetterQ[char], label = char, 
                             If[DigitQ[char], diskRadius = FromDigits[char],
                                              label = ""]]]}
  ]]

(* optional *)
(SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell]; 
 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, CellContents];
 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Character])
```

**Note**: The graphics needs to be focused on.  The `SelectionMove` code accomplishes this programmatically, perhaps ungracefully.  If the user clicks away from the graphics, then keys won't be processed (that is, the user won't be locked into playing with the yellow disk, but can go back to programming).  Clicking on the graphics doesn't get it to listen to keydowns.  Instead, click next to the graphics to the right of it and press the left arrow key.  Perhaps there is a more graceful way to do this!?

[image: Output after pressing "X"]